# How to avoid automatic indents after \input caused by a preceeding line break

Tags: line-breaking, indentation, input

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Some Section}

First (long) paragraph. \\
Second (long) paragraph. \\ 
\input{some_figure}
Third (long) paragraph. \\
Fourth (long) paragraph.

\end{document}
```

where `some_figure.txt` contains

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image} 
\end{figure}
```

The linebreak `\\` after "Second (long) paragraph." causes an automatic indent in the subsequent line "Third (long) paragraph." as one can see in the following figure.

[image].

Is there a way to (automatically) avoid/disable these indents?

I usually move `\input{some_figure}` at the beginning/end of a section to circumvent this problem. However, if the text becomes to large, this is not really an option.

Comment: Don't use ``\\`` to end paragraphs, but a blank line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean actual "paragraphs", then take egreg's advice ("Don't use `\\` to end paragraphs, but a blank line").  But if you are merely forcing linebreaks, then the issue is not one of indent, but of stray spaces.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{some_figure}
\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image} 
\end{figure}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\section{Some Section}

First (long) paragraph. \\
Second (long) paragraph. \\ 
\input some_figure \unskip
Third (long) paragraph. \\
Fourth (long) paragraph.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately,

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{some_figure}
\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image} 
\end{figure}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\section{Some Section}

First (long) paragraph. \\
Second (long) paragraph.
\input some_figure \\
Third (long) paragraph. \\
Fourth (long) paragraph.

\end{document}
```